# In AWK, how to split consecutive rows that have the same string as a "record"?

Tags: string, text, awk, sed

Let's say I have below text.

```
aaaaaaa
aaaaaaa
bbb
bbb
bbb
ccccccccccccc
ddddd
ddddd
```

Is there a way to modify the text as the following.

```
1 aaaaaaa
1 aaaaaaa
2 bbb
2 bbb
2 bbb
3 ccccccccccccc
4 ddddd
4 ddddd
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use something like this in awk:

```
$ awk '{print ($0!=p?++i:i),$0;p=$0}' file
1 aaaaaaa
1 aaaaaaa
2 bbb
2 bbb
2 bbb
3 ccccccccccccc
4 ddddd
4 ddddd
```

`i` is incremented whenever the current line differs from the previous line. `p` holds the value of the previous line, `$0`.

Alternatively, as suggested by [JID](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4453924/jid):

```
awk '$0!=p{p=$0;i++}{print i,$0}' file
```

When the current line differs from `p`, replace `p` and increment `i`. See [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648674/in-awk-how-to-split-consecutive-rows-that-have-the-same-string-as-a-record/29648722?noredirect=1#comment47441043_29648722) for discussion of the pros and cons of either approach :)

A further contribution (and even shorter!) by [NeronLeVelu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2885763/neronlevelu)

```
$ awk '{print i+=($0!=p),p=$0}' file
```

This version performs the addition assignment and basic assignment within the `print` statement. This works because the return value of each assignment is the value that has been assigned.

---

As pointed out in the comments, if the first line of the file is empty, the behaviour changes slightly. Assuming that the first line should always begin with a `1`, the following block can be added to the start of any of the one-liners:

```
NR==1{p=$0;i=1}
```

i.e. on the first line, initialise `p` to the contents of the line (empty or not) and `i` to `1`. Thanks to [Wintermute](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4301306/wintermute) for this suggestion.

Comment: 'Nother way `awk '$0!=p&&p=$0{x++}{print x,$0}'`

Comment: @JID that would fail to increment x if $0 was empty or zero.

Comment: @EdMorton Woops, `awk '$0!=p{p=$0;x++}{print x,$0}'` ?

Comment: @JID that one works (and you shave off a couple of characters, as usual :).

Comment: yeah that'd work but personally I prefer the ternary op solution. nbd but I find it clearest when the `prev` var is set after the code that works on the current record and I know it's less efficient but I also prefer it to be set for every record as every time I see it set conditionally I have to think about whether or not the condition is correct and I try to avoid code that I have to think about :-).

Comment: just for fun `awk '{print i+=($0!=p),$0;p=$0}' ` and also work with `awk '{print i+=($0!=p),p=$0}'` on my system but not sure everywhere

Comment: @NeronLeVelu it's a bit tricky but it I don't see why it shouldn't work, so I've added it into the answer, thanks :)

Comment: This misbehaves if a file begins with an empty line. It's not difficult to fix, mind you; just insert `NR == 1 { p = $0; i = 1 }` before everything else.

Comment: Then it is my pleasure to put a 0 digit back into the score. I've been pondering `uniq -c filename | perl -ape 's/^ *\S* //; $_ = "$. $_" x $F[0]'`, by the way, but it's not exactly sane.

Comment: @Wintermute thanks! In a similar vein to your perl, I came up with `uniq -c file | perl -pe '$_ = "$. $2\n" x $1 if / *(\d) (.*)/'` :)